# how to close pop up cookies module in HTML and bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I need help how to close the popup module in bootstrap when the user accepts or cancels.
For the life of me, I can't figure out how to close it I seem to have forgotten

```
<div class="cookie-consent"> <span>This site uses cookies to enhance user experience. see<a href="privacy.html" class="ml-1 text-decoration-none"> &nbsp;Privacy policy &nbsp;</a> </span>
    <div class=" ml-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center g-2"> <button class="allow-button mr-1">Allow cookies</button> <button class="allow-button">cancel</button> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using [Bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) ?

There is `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` attribute you can add to your `button` tag, is that working ?

Comment: yes i am good now they answered above thanks a lot for the support

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function closeCookies() {
  document.getElementById("cookie-div").style="display:none"
}
</script>
<div id="cookie-div" class="cookie-consent"> <span>This site uses cookies to enhance user experience. see<a href="privacy.html" class="ml-1 text-decoration-none"> &nbsp;Privacy policy &nbsp;</a> </span>
    <div class=" ml-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center g-2"> <button onclick="closeCookies()" class="allow-button mr-1">Allow cookies</button> <button class="allow-button" onclick="closeCookies()">cancel</button> </div>
</div>
```

This has some javascript code which defines a function called "closeCookies". This function gets the element with the id "cookie-div" and sets the display to none, meaning that everything inside the div should dissappear, too. The button calls the closeCookies function which is what we just defined, causing the cookie-consent div to dissappear.

Comment: @ΘΗΣΈΑΣ Could you please mark the answer as correct if it worked?